# Font error in html

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, fonts

My website has a font error, when I open the chrome developer tool, I see the image as attached.
My error text is hard-coded.
I added a meta tag utf-8 to the head tag.

I do not understand why it's buggy, while still having one of my pages using the same code does not get this error.

Help me
Thanks

[image]

Comment: what cms are you using !?

Comment: I use Microsft's C# language (MVC
)

Comment: see this documentation it may help you [->link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding)

Comment: can you show the  code that generate this page !?

Comment: My code is like in the image, but the word is accented, I fix hard code, but to run it is so wrong. My accented letters are wrongly coded

Answer (score 0):

First of all use in your head section:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Second: when you are saving your HTML files,
please try to use NOTEPAD before putting files on the server.
The reason for that is, you may use some editor that 
converts your characters in a way that gives an error...

Comment: As I said, I added the utf-8 meta tag as you said, but it still does not work properly

Comment: try second part: when you are saving your HTML files, please try to use NOTEPAD before putting files on the server. I had the same problem and it worked for me.